# Primefaces JSF Opening a dialog multiple times slowly increases browser memory

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces, memory-leaks

I am using Primefaces 4.0, JSF 2.1.11

I have a page with a button that calls a prime-faces dialog.show() and a dialog appears after filling it out click done and it refreshes the page with the new item added into a prime-faces dataTable.  Everytime I click the button to open the dialog and fill it out then hit done my browser memory goes up.  In automation testing once the dialog has been opened 125 times (our users could do this up to 800 times in a row) the browser runs out of memory. In IE8 at 125 items the memory usage was at 880 MB.

So my question is how do I prevent this?

more Info:  Beans are viewscoped, using Glassfish 3, this issue happens in all browsers but worse in older browsers.

Steps I have taken:
1.  I am doing a .show() .hide() each time on the dialog.
2. I have tried to call javascript to empty out the divs in the DOM without any success.

I have looked on primefaces issues and I dont see any memory leak reports, also if I let the page sit open the memory doesn't go up, its only when I am using the page and opening and closing the dialog.

UPDATE:

Here is some code

this form is outside the other form

```
  <h:form id="lineItemForm">
        <p:dialog id="addLineItemDialogId" widgetVar="lineItemDialog" header="Line item" width="900" resizable="false"
          modal="true" showEffect="fade">

... 
...


             <p:commandLink value="Done"
                            onclick="actionStarted($(this))"
                            action="#{lineItemView.save}"
                            update=":wizardForm:lineItemWizardPanel"
                            oncomplete="actionComplete(); saveLineItem(args);"/>

    </h:form>
```

The saveLineItem(args) is a javascript method that calls .hide() after validation check

Here is the call to .show() it is in the form wizardForm.

```
    <h:form id="wizardForm"/>
...
...
          <p:commandLink value="Add Item"
                        action="#{lineItemView.loadLineItemFromRequest(requisitionView.request)}"
                        process="@this"
                        update=":lineItemForm"
                        oncomplete="lineItemDialog.show()"/>
```

**UPDATE**  So It ended up being a red hering.  I removed the backend method call and the memory leak went away.  It looks likes its the dataTable causeing the issue, with ajax.  Looked it up and it is fixed in Primefaces 5 
http://www.beyondjava.net/blog/primefaces-5/

Comment: Do you have any code to share?

Comment: I will check if this behavior happens to me too. I'm using dialog to store and show huge amount of data with detailed description for each data table row.

Comment: Do you `update` the dialog (or a parent to the dialog) before showing it?

Comment: I'm having no problem with my dialog and I'm updating the same dialog clicking in some datatable row.

Comment: Yes I update the form the dialog is in before showing it, and the dialog is not in the same form as the commandLink calling show() and the dataTable displaying results

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a guess although I am not sure. Try structuring the code like this:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form id="mainForm">
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
    </h:form>

    <p:dialog>
        <h:form id="dialogForm">
            ...
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

And on the button you use to show the dialog use `update="dialogForm"`.

I believe that if you `update` the dialog itself or one of its parents, it can result in several dialogs hiding each other. That might explain the memory usage. Besides it is best practise to have the dialogs in the end outside of the main form.